# ajax in wp front end

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I want to use ajax in wp plugin front end not the admin pages,
I used wp_localize_script() to be able to access ajaxurl in front end 
and it works.
Here is my ajax code

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

function commonProvinceChange() {

    $j(".province").change(function() {
       var selectedProvinceId = $j(this).val();
       var districts = "<option disabled selected='selected'>Select District</option>";
       $j.post(naqdina_map.ajaxurl, {
         province_id : selectedProvinceId,
         action : 'province_districts'
        }, function(data, status) {
          alert(naqdina_map.ajaxurl);
                            data = JSON.parse(data);
                            $j(".district").html(districts);
                            for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                $j(".district").append(
                                        "<option value=" + data[i].id + ">"
                                                + data[i].district_name
                                                + "</option>");
                            }// for
                        });

                    });
}// commonProvinceChange()
```

and on my plugin php file

```
function naqdina_front_script() {

    wp_enqueue_script ( 'jquery' );

    wp_register_script ( 'naqdina_map_script', plugins_url ( 'naqdina_map/map.js', __FILE__ ), array (
            'jquery' 
    ) );
    wp_localize_script('naqdina_map_script','naqdina_map',array('ajaxurl'=>admin_url('ajax-admin.php')));
    wp_enqueue_script ( 'naqdina_map_script' );
}//naqdina_front_script()

add_action ( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'naqdina_front_script' );
```

and then

```
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_province_districts', 'province_districts' );

function province_districts() {

    global $wpdb;

        $province_id = $_POST ['province_id'];

    $pname = $wpdb->get_results ( "select d.id,d.name as district_name from naqdina_districts as d join naqdina_provinces as p on(d.province_id=p.id) where p.id='" . $province_id . "'" );

    echo json_encode ( $pname );
    die (); // use die() to prevent further content

} // province_districts()
```

here the post() method in my js code above returns html code of the whole page not the the response echoed by province_districts() function.

Could someone help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_province_districts', 'province_districts' );` to use AJAX in the frontend.

EDIT: In `map.js` on line 9 you are POSTing to `""` which resolves as a relative URL to the current page.  If you replace that with `naqdina_map.ajaxurl` your code will work.

[image: Edit: This is what you need to do.]

Comment: I added the code 
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_province_districts', 'province_districts' );
still it is not working. the ajax response is the whole html code of the site home page.

Comment: Sounds like your ajaxurl variable doesn't contain the right value.  It might be a scoping issue, or something else obscure.  Can you link to the site that you're working on?

Comment: Your code in the map.js file is out-of-date or incorrect.  Check `map.js` line 9 - you aren't using `naqdina_map.ajaxurl` in your POST.  I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: naqdina_map.ajaxurl gives "http://naqdina.midsconsulting.com/wp-admin/ajax-admin.php"
i placed naqdina_map.ajaxurl in $j.post();
still it redirects me to the home page

Comment: Yes, but your map.js file is not referring to that variable.

Comment: in map.js console.log(naqdina_map.ajaxurl) gives the http://naqdina.midsconsulting.com/wp-admin/ajax-admin.php

Comment: Please check the image I just posted in the answer.

Comment: thanks for your patient. i checked the image and just updated map.js accordingly still it is not working.

Comment: I just refreshed the link you gave me and it has not been updated.  It still shows what is shown in the screenshot.  I guarantee you that this is the correct fix.  If it is not working for you, you are not updating the correct file, or you are not uploading your changes.

Please double-check your work.

Comment: I've just seen that you've updated your site and it's still not working, though at least it's making the request to the right page now.  Can you post your nginx config for that site please?  It appears the problem is a server-side rewrite, since the admin-ajax.php file is not being hit.

Comment: thanks again, but i don't know about 'nginx config' file, which directory i may find that file?
I'm using wp version 3.9.1

Comment: That will be dependent on your web server configuration.  It isn't part of wordpress.  Do you know if your server uses Apache with mod-php or PHP-FPM?

Comment: Bundle of thanks to Dan Cowell,
I solved my problem, replacing
wp_localize_script('naqdina_map_script','naqdina_map',array('ajaxurl'=>admin_url('ajax-admin.php')));
with wp_localize_script('naqdina_map_script','naqdina_map',array('ajaxurl'=>admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I had a ridiculous mistake.
It is **admin-ajax.php** not **ajax-admin.php**.
Replacing

```
wp_localize_script('naqdina_map_script','naqdina_map',array('ajaxurl'=>admin_url('ajax-admin.php')));
```

with

```
wp_localize_script('naqdina_map_script','naqdina_map',array('ajaxurl'=>admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
```

solved my problem.